in Pine Script 5 Tradingview to light a candle by timestamp
I can't understand how I can highlight a candle with a time point, for example April 30, 2024 23:59:00.
indicator("Highlight Specific Time", overlay=true)

specifiedTime = timestamp("GMT+0", 2024, 04, 30, 23, 59)

plotshape(series=(time == specifiedTime), location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, style=shape.arrowdown, size=size.large, title="Specific Time Marker")

I read the Pine Script manual and couldn't find how to mark a candle according to the set time
